# How to raise an error when testing a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pyodbc

I'm trying to do a very simple test where my function takes in one parameter, a path to a database, tries to connect to the database using pyodbc.connect(database path) and if the path is invalid raises an error. However, as my test is structured currently, I am unable to make the test pass (raise the error) when I pass the function being tested a bad path.

I've tried to pass the test using mocks and without mocks. I believe the correct way to go would be to use mocks, however I also could not get that to work (see code below). I've found questions that were similar to what issue I'm having, but I could not use the suggestions in those questions to get my test to work.

## Function Being Tested

```
import pyodbc

# When function runs by itself (no test) pyodbc.InterfaceError is raised if database path is bad! 
def connect_to_database(database):  
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(database)
        return conn
    except pyodbc.InterfaceError as err:
        raise err
```

## Tests

### Without mocking

```
def test_invalid_path_to_database(self):
    self.assertRaises(pyodbc.InterfaceError, connect_to_database, '')
```

### With mocking

```
def setUp(self):
    self.mock_conn= mock.patch('my_package.my_module.pyodbc.connect').start()
        self.addCleanup(mock.patch.stopall)

def test_invalid_path_to_database(self):
    self.mock_conn.side_effect = pyodbc.InterfaceError
    self.assertRaises(pyodbc.InterfaceError, connect_to_database, '')
```

I expect when the passed database path to the function is not valid an error (in this case InterfaceError) should be raised and the test should pass. This is not happening as the test is structured.

Comment: The test without mocking isn't raising an error?

Comment: why not pass ‘pyodbc’ into the function, but in the test pass self in?

Comment: Yes I'm getting "AssertionError: InterfaceError not raised by connect_to_database". But that means the test is failing, and that's not what I want when parameter for the function is bad database path. I want it to pass when that's the case

Comment: The parameter (database path) is coming from another module. Ideally, I prefer to pass in the path and check if it's valid within the function if possible

Comment: Are you sure you're checking for the correct exception?

Comment: I think so. When I run the function on it's own and use ' ' in place of the database parameter, I get " pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') "

Comment: @OskiTuranoglu, you want to test for that exception then `except pyodbc.InterfaceError as err` not `pyodbc.Error`. Those are different classes and `pyodbc.Error` might not even exist.

Comment: Sorry , please disregard my previous comment. It did not work as intended. Even after the change as you rightly pointed out, if the parameter for the callable is given as an invalid path the test still fails, when it should pass because the error should be raised.```self.assertRaises(pyodbc.InterfaceError, connect_to_database, '')``` --> AssertionError: InterfaceError not raised by connect_to_database